# Wifi doesn't work after suspend/sleep

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

I know a lot of people have similar issues but my laptop worked fine for almost a year.
For some reason at some point last week this bug started to reproduce on my machine. I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.
Fortunately, restarting network manager does the trick but I want to figure out what caused the regression. I don't see anything suspicious in syslog but I'm not an expert in it. Maybe someone can prodive a descriptive answer based on the syslog or explain why restarting network manager helps in more detail?
Attaching my [syslog](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/73005d0f4bebc5391b14640119e377ad)